# tensorflow Optimizer.py "optimizer._get_variable_for" file function

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I am trying to implement an Optimizer in tensorflow, and have been looking at optimizer code from old version of tensorflow, and want to understand what does this function `_get_variable_for` do? It is the first function in the optimizer file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanking You.

Answer (score -1):

I see that this function checks two conditions.

*ResourceVariable* and *VarHandleOp*

This is a *ResourceVariable* according to the comments in the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py)

"For example, if there is more than one assignment to a ResourceVariable in
  a single session.run call there is a well-defined value for each operation
  which uses the variable's value if the assignments and the read are connected
  by edges in the graph. Consider the following example, in which two writes
  can cause tf.Variable and tf.ResourceVariable to behave differently:"

```
  a = tf.Variable(1.0, use_resource=True)
  a.initializer.run()
  assign = a.assign(2.0)
  with tf.control_dependencies([assign]):
    b = a.read_value()
  with tf.control_dependencies([b]):
    other_assign = a.assign(3.0)
  with tf.control_dependencies([other_assign]):
    # Will print 2.0 because the value was read before other_assign ran. If
    # `a` was a tf.Variable instead, 2.0 or 3.0 could be printed.
    tf.Print(b, [b]).eval()
```

*VarHandleOp* seems to have deeper semantics as per [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_guide)

"A common approach to managing where variables are placed, is to create a method to determine where each Op is to be placed and use that method in place of a specific device name when calling with `tf.device():` Consider a scenario where a model is being trained on 2 GPUs and the variables are to be placed on the CPU. There would be a loop for creating and placing the "towers" on each of the 2 GPUs. A custom device placement method would be created that watches for Ops of type Variable, VariableV2, and VarHandleOp and indicates that they are to be placed on the CPU. All other Ops would be placed on the target GPU."

It explains this scenario further with sample code.